# JSON Unicode escape sequence - lowercase or not?

Tags: json, unicode, language-lawyer, rfc

I was reading RFC 4627 and I can't figure out if the following is valid JSON or not. Consider this minimalistic JSON text:

```
["\u005c"]
```

The problem is the **lowercase** `c`.

According to the *text* of the RFC it is allowed:

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
>   represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
>   by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
>   encode the character's code point.  **The hexadecimal letters A though
>   F can be upper or lowercase.**  So, for example, a string containing
>   only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
>   "\u005C".

(Emphasis mine)

The problem is that the RFC also contains the *grammar* for this:

```lisp
char = unescaped /
       escape (
           %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
           %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
           %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
           %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
           %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
           %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
           %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
           %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
           %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
```

where `HEXDIG` is defined in referenced RFC 4234 as

```
HEXDIG         =  DIGIT / "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"
```

which includes only uppercase letters.

FWIW, from what I researched most JSON parsers accept both upper and lowercase letters.

**Question(s)**: What is actually correct? Is there a contradiction and the grammar in the RFC should be fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *think* it's explained by this part of RFC 4234:

> ABNF strings are case-insensitive and the character set for these strings is us-ascii.
>
> Hence:
>
> ```
>     rulename = "abc"
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
>     rulename = "aBc"
> ```
>
> will match "abc", "Abc", "aBc", "abC", "ABc", "aBC", "AbC", and
>      "ABC".

On the other hand, the follow-on part is not terribly clear:

> To specify a rule that IS case SENSITIVE, specify the characters individually.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     rulename    =  %d97 %d98 %d99
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>     rulename    =  %d97.98.99
> ```

In the case of the `HEXDIG` rule, they're individual characters to start with - but they're specified literally as `"A"` etc rather than `%d41`, so I *suspect* that means they're case-insensitive. It's not the clearest spec I've read :(

Comment: Doesn't that just refer to the grammar of writing other grammars? I mean it allows `HEXDIG` and `heXdIG` to be used interchangeably, but the surely can't refer to all characters in the grammar like `"A"`, otherwise you could not define **any** case-sensitive language!?

Comment: @DanielFrey: I don't think so - that's a separate part of the RFC: "Rule names are case-insensitive". I agree that it's far from clear though.

Comment: +1 I wrote the first comment before your edit. With the edit it makes sense now and yes, I agree it's not the clearest spec :)

Comment: And all the case-sensitive keywords in the JSON defining RFC 4627 are provided using individual characters (with ASCII literal in a comment after it), like `false = %x66.61.6c.73.65   ; false`.